# Merge multiple document ready functions into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this $(document).ready function:

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Form_Page_3').bootstrapValidator();
   });`

And wanted to combine these next two functions into the first function above, is there any way to achieve this? My aim is for the '.bootstrapValidator();' to validate not just '#Form_Page_3' but also '#Form_Page_1' and '#Form_Page_2'. Many thanks in advance :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Form_Page_1').bootstrapValidator();
      });
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Form_Page_2').bootstrapValidator();
      });
```

This is the code for my register button that works when the single function is used but not when i try to combine the 3

`<div class="form-group formSubmit">
         <div class="col-sm-12 submitWrap">
            <input type="submit" name = "register" value="Register" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" form="Form_Page_1">
         </div>`

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get all elements with `id`'s that start with `Form_Page`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=Form_Page]').bootstrapValidator();
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

---

If the above throws errors because `.bootstrapValidator()` doesn't support multiple objects, use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=Form_Page]').each(function(){ $(this).bootstrapValidator(); });
});
```

Comment: I just tried the second piece of code you suggested and still didnt have any luck, im making a login system and the validation is successful on all 3 forms however now when i go to submit the submit button doesnt work with, it used to work with the code in my question.

Comment: @LiamBaker "the submit button doesnt work" Can you include that in your question? We can't help you fix problems you never mentioned.

Comment: @LiamBaker From where does `.bootstrapValidator()` come?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Form_Page_1').bootstrapValidator({/* options for form 1 */});
    $('#Form_Page_2').bootstrapValidator({/* options for form 2 */});
    // etc.
});
```